# laravel all urls 404 without index.php

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, laravel-5

Every thing is working fine including HTTP to https redirection on browsers

```
http://example.com/app/login  404
https://example.com/app/login 404
http://www.example.com/app/login 404
https://www.example.com/app/login 404

http://example.com/index.php/app/login  OK
https://example.com/app/index.php/login OK
http://www.example.com/index.php/app/login OK
https://www.example.com/index.php/app/login OK
```

URLs tested with postman

http to https redirection works fine respecting www or non www

Server 
Ubuntu 18.04
Apache 2.4.29

```
/etc/hosts  

 206.189.85.* example.com #server ip address
 206.189.85.* www.example.com
 127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public

    <Directory /var/www/example.com/public/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiVies
        AllowOverride All      
        Require all granted     
     </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public

    SSLEngine On

    <Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All       
        Require all granted
     </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess content

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>


    RewriteEngine On



    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off   
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

add DirectoryIndex & Redirect permanent to your virtualhost:80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
DirectoryIndex index.php
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/

<Directory /var/www/example.com/public/>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiVies
    AllowOverride All      
    Require all granted     
 </Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Http to https redirection is working fine , only problem is with index.php in url

Comment: Tried adding in conf and in htaccess reenabled conf but still the error persists.

Comment: can you post htaccess content

Answer (score 0):

check list

1. is your apache a2enmod rewrite enabled ?

   command to enable

   sudo a2enmod rewrite

   sudo service apache2 restart
2. add this line in end .htaccess

   RewriteRule . ^ index.php [L]

   check this thread for more info
   [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

Answer (score 0):

Can you change 
`RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]`
to
`RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`

Edit:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Can you check with this Rewrite rules. If working add your https and authentication conditions later.

Comment: No help still the issue persists